# Unable to use result of aggregation with pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using aggregation for get the data I need.

```
app.post('/test3', function(request,response){

    var pipeline = [{$unwind:"$inventar"}
    ,{$match:{"tablename":tablename,"inventar.isstammkost":true,"inventar.accepted":"1"}}
    ,{$project : { "inventar" : 1}}
    ,{$group : {_id : null, Inventar : { $push:"$inventar"}}}]
    Move.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, res) {
    //var InvObj = res2.toObject();
    console.log(res);
    response.json(res);
    }); 
   });
```

I don't understand the result of the aggregation:
The `console.log(res)` gives
`[ { _id: null, Inventar: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]`
and `response.json(res)` gives

```
[1]
    0:  {
    _id: null
    Inventar: [2]
    0:  {
    accepted: "1"
    ean: "802.6784.232"
    isstammkost: true
    stammkost: "IWXI"
    }-
    1:  {
    accepted: "1"
    ean: "802.2000.100"
    isstammkost: true
    stammkost: "IWXI"
    }
    }
```

Why I can't make a JavascriptObject with `var Obj = res.toObject();`?
I get `undefined` if I try it.
I need to acces the array "Inventar" in the object.

Comment: It's already just a plain object, just an array of plain objects in the result, though only one because everything groups to a single result via `null` as a grouping key. Therefore `res` is an "array" and `res[0]` is just the single object element. You don't need `.toObject()` since this is not a "mongoose document" anymore as the resulting fields have nothing to do with the original model definition. `console.dir(res[0])` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, its not a object with {}. The result of aggregation is an array.

Comment: Yes the result of `.aggregate()` just like the result of `.find()` is always a "list", no matter how many results are actually returned. Simply access each required element in the list, or just send it serialized as such and expect a list.

Comment: You can answer it , so I can mark it as solved. Thank you